# ASP.NET & Javascript confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a confirmation dialog that's made using JavaScript library, I want to make it appear when the user tries to delete a row from gridview. The thing with this library is that it doesn't use confirm function in JavaScript instead it shows a custom popup, once the user clicks Yes it executes a call back function, once the user clicks No it executes another call back function.

When using this library with server side event, the server side event doesn't wait for the confirmation as it's not the javascript confirm function, so how do I make the server side code wait from a result of the call back in my JS alert if yes or no?

I am new to development in general so thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to bind the javascript function to be called to the `OnClientClick` property and `OnClick` will be binded to the server-side event.

In that javascript function, which will be called first, before the server-side event, you'll have to return either `true` or `false`.

If `true`, the server-side event will execute, if `false`, there won't even be a post back. Based on your comments and your plugin, you could do it like this

```
function sampleFunction() {
    var flag = false; // maintain a flag
    alertify.confirm("This is a confirm dialog.", function() {
        flag = true; // set it true here
    }, function(){});
    return flag; // return the flag
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, the server code doesn't wait for the user to click either Yes or No, it displays the pop up and continues with the server code as if it's OK.

Comment: @Richard yes. If it is okay, it will execute server-side, but not if the confirm is "No"

Comment: OK that was a problem for me, had the code cached. Now here is my code  `var tag = false;  
            alertify.confirm(Title, function (e) {  
                if (e) {  
                    tag= true;  
                }  
                else {  
                    tag = false;  
                }  
                            return tag;  

            });return tag`

Comment: @Richard if it is working now, then please consider accepting my answer by clicking the tick mark

Comment: It's not working :( It's not accepting the Yes choice now. I click Yes or No and it's taking it as false. Something is wrong with callback functions.

Comment: @Richard use MY code. You've not specified the second function

Comment: It should be `var tag = false; alertify.confirm(Title, function () {  tag= true; }, function(){}); return tag;`

Comment: Thanks Amit, if you try the code on your side, you will notice that the return tag is only stepped on when the pop up is viewed, but when you click Yes or No the debugger doesn't step on the return flag.

Comment: That's because on click is calling the popup. After calling the popup everything related to the click is gone. So it returned false from the beginning. and the code stopped, it didn't really wait for the user to choose YES/NO.

Comment: @Richard I don't get you. Now do this. Go to alertifyjs.com and then paste the code - `var flag = false;
alertify.confirm("This is a confirm dialog.",function () {
    flag = true;
},function () {});
alert("It works really well!!!");
alert(flag);
`

Comment: Thanks Amit. This whole code is called from a Delete button on a gridview ok? So once you click Delete, the code snippet that you wrote will be called, and it will return false. So the server side code is in fact stopped. But now whatever the user clicks either YES/NO on the confirm dialog, it doesn't do anything. They are both false now. because we already returned the value when the popup opened. You got me?

Comment: make a fiddle @Richard

Comment: Thanks Amit, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/d09429p1/1/  As you can see, the return is only steped on once you click the button. After that the YES/NO actions are not taken into account. You can see that in debug mode.

Comment: @Richard yeah. It is sort of weird.

Comment: I guess it's normal as it's not build like the JS confirm functionality which will really wait for bool. In my case the code is finished once the popup is shown. So it's always false. Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: @Richard thinking on it. It is asynchronous. Can't you just use `confirm`?

Comment: I am using the same Alertify module in all my project, it happened that I am using this confirm for the first time.

Comment: Hi Amit, as you can see in the fiddle, it's not waiting for the result from the buttons YES/NO